# Limit web page to 1 session per page Django

Tags: python, django, session

[Use case]
Our django application utilizes AJAX and allows multiple writers and editor to view and edit a single article.

Our Django application has the following session management requirements.

1. Only allows 1 authenticated user on the page at any 1 time.
2. Sessions expire when the user closes the window or exits the page.
3. Sessions expire after a period of inactivity
4. If the user is active on the app, the session must not time out.

Currently I have been looking into the sessions model however I have not seen any solutions to limit the page to only 1 user.

Thanks!

Comment: Conceptually: Set a global boolean to True when you have 1 user, and false when you have 0 users. If True the user cannot log in.

Comment: Thanks! great input.

However I have some doubts on my ability to extend the user session using django signals (call a extend session from jquery should the user click yes, extend session).

Comment: You don't have to extend the session, it extends "automatically" when the user is performing activities. Read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions

Answer (score 2):

Blocking decorator:

```
def view_only_by_one(key_function=lambda request: sha256(request.path).hexdigest()):
    def __dec(the_view):
        def __inner(request, *args, **kwargs):                
            key_for_view = key_function(request)
            current_blocked = request.session.get('blocked_view'):
            if current_blocked and current_blocked != key_for_view:
                 cache.set(key, None, timeout=0)
            user_id = cache.get(key_for_view)
            if user_id and user_id != request.user.id:
               raise PermissionDenied()
            cache.set(key, request.user.id, timeout=settings.ONLY_BY_ONE_BLOCK_TIME)
            request.session['blocked_view'] = key_for_view
            return the_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
       return __inner
    return __dec
```

Additionally you can have a unblocking view called by ajax and removes lock (read from session) on page exit. Session + cache is the simplest solution, but it's easy to change it to db version.

Comment: whoa.. 1 second reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python to catch up with your code now.

Comment: i made mistake, now is fixed. view_only_by_one function produces decorator, usage: @view_only_by_one()\ndef my_view(request): ...

Comment: where would i put this decorator in??